# How are strings represented in the Minecraft network protocol?

Tags: minecraft

I'm trying to interpret the following:

https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Data_types

In it, a `String(n)` is described as:

> UTF-8 string prefixed with its size in bytes as a VarInt. Maximum length of n characters, which varies by context; up to n × 4 bytes can be used to encode n characters and both of those limits are checked. Maximum n value is 32767. The + 3 is due to the max size of a valid length VarInt.

But this is contradictory. It says that the size of the string is given "in bytes as a VarInt", but from there, it introduces `n`, which is not the number of *bytes* (octets) but the number of *Unicode characters*. The rest of the description is written as if the number you'll have in advance of reading is not the actual number of bytes, but `n`, the number of Unicode characters.

So which is it? Are these strings prefixed with the number of *bytes*, or the number of *Unicode characters*?

Also, what character(s) is used to terminate lines in this protocol? CR, LF, or CR/LF?